# AD Azure Graph API does not return directorylinkchanges

Tags: rest, azure

I am using differential query feature provided by AD Azure graph apis as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj836245.aspx)
Things are working fine except for one issue. The sample responses in the link show that membership changes are sent across as directorylinkchange objects but I do not receive any such objects with similar queries on making membership changes from the portal. 
I am doing a GET to

```
https://graph.windows.net/<domain-name>/directoryObjects?api-version=2013-04-05&$filter=isof('Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Group')%20or%20isof('Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.User')&deltaLink=cLbsN4TzLm92uH26XEe7Ph6HfE10VkRsxjmz8 ..[truncated]
```

I am not sure if I am missing something here as I am able to fetch other User and Group changes. So could anyone working on azure be able help me out on this one. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. answer to my own question is , that the URL filter must contain all three object classes User, Group and Contact just like it is in the microsoft sample.

```
https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/directoryObjects?api-version=2013-04-05&$filter=isof('Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.User')%20or%20isof('Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Group')%20or%20isof('Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Contact')
```